# error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++

alguien sabe como solucionar este "error"? intente varias cosas y ver publicaciones similares pero la verdad que no encontré ninguna solución, recién hoy empecé en c++ y
este código me funciona bien en c.

Por alguna razon que desconozco al intentar usar los set (de char) me tira el error:

***warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
12 |        setData(usuario1,"franco");**

pd: puse asi el main porque de todas formas si creo el user completo también me tira error con todos los char

```
int main(void){

       dataUser usuario1 = crearUser();
       
       setData(usuario1,"franco");

    return 0;
}
```

De esta forma que tengo definido el cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "info.hpp"

struct userData{
    int ID;
    char nameYsurname[20];
    char data[20];
    int listVinos;
    int edad;
    char nacionalidad[20];
};
//---------------------------Constructores---------------------------------------------
dataUser crearUser(){
    dataUser user = new struct userData;
    return user;
};
dataUser crearUser(int ID,char nameYsurname[],char data[],int listVinos,int edad,char nacionalidad[]){
    dataUser user = new struct userData;
    
        setID(user,ID);
        setNameYsurname(user,nameYsurname);
        setData(user,data);
        setListVinos(user,listVinos);
        setEdad(user,edad);
        setNacionalidad(user,nacionalidad);

    return user;
};
//---------------------------Getters-------------------------------------------------
int getID(dataUser u1){
    return u1->ID;
};
char* getNameYsurname(dataUser u1){
    return u1->nameYsurname;
};
char* getData(dataUser u1){
    return u1->data;
};
int getListVinos(dataUser u1){
    return u1->listVinos;
};
int getEdad(dataUser u1){
    return u1->edad;
};
char* getNacionalidad(dataUser u1){
    return u1->nacionalidad;
};
//---------------------------Setters-------------------------------------------------
void setID(dataUser u1,int NewID){
//    do{
    u1->ID = NewID;
//    if(NewID < 10000 || NewID > 99999){
//        std::cout<<"Solo ID's de 5 digitos por favor: "<<std::endl;
//    }
//    }while(NewID < 10000 || NewID > 99999);
};
void setNameYsurname(dataUser u1,char newName[]){
    strcpy(u1->nameYsurname,newName);
};
void setData(dataUser u1,char newData[]){
    strcpy(u1->data,newData);
};
void setListVinos(dataUser u1,int newListVinos){
    u1->listVinos = newListVinos;
};
void setEdad(dataUser u1,int newEdad){
    u1->edad = newEdad;
};
void setNacionalidad(dataUser u1,char newNacionalidad[]){
    strcpy(u1->nacionalidad,newNacionalidad);
};
//---------------------------Destructor---------------------------------------------
void deleteUser(dataUser u1){
    delete(u1);
};
```

Comment: El problema tal vez está en que estas pasando un string literal como char*. Tienes dos opciones: o cambiar el tipo de argumento que recibe la funcion de char* a const char*, o pasarle el argumento convertido a char* de la forma (char*)"franco" pero no es recomendable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta función:

```
setData(usuario1,"franco");
```

El segundo parámetro es un literal, es decir, es un valor constante, porque ¿De qué manera podría el programa modificar alguno de esos caracters que están escritos a fuego en el programa?

Pues bien, en la función `setData`

```
void setData(dataUser u1,char newData[])
```

Vemos que el segundo parámetro que recibe no es constante. Y es aquí donde empiezan los problemas, porque:

1. En C++ el tipado es fuerte y hay que respetarlo
2. Una variable puede pasar a ser constante en un momento dado, pero una constante no puede dejar de serlo nunca
3. ¿Cómo se modifica algo constante?

El caso es que el compilador no te va a dejar hacer esa llamada, ya que entonces la función `setData` tendría libertad para cambiar el contenido de ese literal, lo cual no es posible porque, insisto, es un literal.

La solución es tan simple como pasar a usar parámetros constantes:

```
void setData(dataUser u1,char const* newData)
```

O, si lo prefieres declarar a la vieja usanza

```
void setData(dataUser u1,const char newData[])
```

El efecto es el mismo, yo prefiero agrupar todos los modificadores (puntero, referencia, constante) en un mismo punto